# What was the first SciFi work that theorized that Homo Sapiens were seeded on Earth by intelligent aliens?

Tags: aliens, history-of, science-fiction-genre, alternate-history, evolution

What was the first SciFi work that theorized that Homo Sapiens were seeded on Earth by intelligent aliens (as opposed to all the other Earth species which evolved separately)?

The earliest one I can think of was David Weber's Dahak trilogy (aka "Empire from the Ashes", but the first book was only released in 1991 ("Mutineer's Moon") and I am pretty sure the idea predates that. In the book, modern humans are descendants of the crew of a planetoid-sized warship stranded in Solar system 50,000 years ago.

The question is very specific to aliens seeding Humans as a species as-is. The answers where life in general was seeded prior to Humans evolving from that earlier life (ala *Star Trek*'s  Preservers from "The Chase"); or Humans existed but were raised to intelligence (ala "2001") are NOT what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are there Scifi works that theorize homo-sapiens being seeded by unintelligent aliens?

Comment: @Xantec - HS probably no, but there probably are plenty covering Panspermia theory) which frequently is sourced in non-intelligent "biological contamination" from elsewhere.

Comment: Is this limited to modern works of fiction, or are ancient stories acceptable?

Comment: @GorchestopherH - ancient stories are acceptable, but must involve "normal" extraterrestrial aliens originated on other planets, and not gods - which would probably disqualify most/all of them.

Comment: At a time when kings were often deified, it is mostly impossible to expect that beings with abilities outside of their own means were not coined "gods".

Comment: See also http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Panspermia for examples of both directed and undirected Panspermia.

Comment: Indeed, I misread the question.

Comment: @user14111 - haven't had a chance to analyze properly yet, sorry. Answering old questions is a Good Thing (anything that has a badge for it is considered Good). Inquiruing OP's opinion is not a bad form as far as I'm aware, but reactions from different people may vary :)

Comment: DVK - You wrote: "The answers where life in general was seeded prior to Humans evolving from that earlier life (ala Star Trek's Preservers from "The Chase")..."  But the Preservers were from TOS "The Paradise Syndrome" and the aliens in TNG "The Chase" lived billions of years before the Preservers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H. Beam Piper's Paratime series takes as its premise the idea that humans came originally from Mars.  In the first story to explain this ("Police Operation" (1948)) we have

> "Purely arbitrary terms. There are five main probability levels,
> derived from the five possible outcomes of the attempt to colonize
> this planet, seventy-five thousand years ago. We're on the First
> Level—complete success, and colony fully established. The Fifth Level
> is the probability of complete failure—no human population established
> on this planet, and indigenous quasi-human life evolved indigenously.
> On the Fourth Level, the colonists evidently met with some disaster
> and lost all memory of their extraterrestrial origin, as well as all
> extraterrestrial culture. As far as they know, they are an indigenous
> race; they have a long pre-history of stone-age savagery.
>
> "Sectors are areas of paratime on any level in which the prevalent
> culture has a common origin and common characteristics. They are
> divided more or less arbitrarily into sub-sectors. Belts are areas
> within sub-sectors where conditions are the result of recent alternate
> probabilities. For instance, I've just come from the Europo-American
> Sector of the Fourth Level, an area of about ten thousand parayears in
> depth, in which the dominant civilization developed on the North-West
> Continent of the Major Land Mass, and spread from there to the Minor
> Land Mass. The line on which I was operating is also part of a
> sub-sector of about three thousand parayears' depth, and a belt
> developing from one of several probable outcomes of a war concluded
> about three elapsed years ago. On that time-line, the field at the
> Hagraban Synthetics Works, where we took off, is part of an abandoned
> farm; on the site of Hagraban City is a little farming village. Those
> things are there, right now, both in primary time and in the plenum.
> They are about two hundred and fifty thousand parayears perpendicular
> to each other, and each is of the same general order of reality."

So our civilization is on the Fourth Level - we came from Mars, but don't know it.

Comment: As noted by other works, this isn't even close to the first.

Comment: Someday I'll learn to read the rest of the thread more carefully.

Comment: I read right past the 1897 example.

Answer (score 30):

[Chad Oliver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chad_Oliver)'s 1959 novelette ["Transfusion"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfusion_(short_story)) (first published in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, June 1959](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57554+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v63n04_1959-06_EXciter-LennyS#page/n43/mode/2up))
was not the first, but it's a very good example of that microgenre.

But you asked for the first one. In his book [*Science-Fiction: The Early Years*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Science_fiction_the_Early_Years.html?id=KEZxhkG5eikC) Everett F. Bleiler reviews virtually every work of science fiction ever written, from the beginning of time to 1930. The index lists 15 works under the heading "Human race originated elsewhere", classified as follows:

Alpha centauri (1)
Hollow earth (5)
Mars (2)
Mercury (1)
Moon (6)
Nevada (1)
Saturn (1)
Space spirits, plus pithecanthropus (1)
Venus (1)

These add up to more than 15 because one story has repeated colonizations of earth from different planets. After discarding hollow earth, Nevada, and space spirits as not the kind of "elsewhere" we're looking for, the earliest one seems to be ["The Judgment Day in the Moon"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1618583), a short story by [Walter Malone](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?131177), included in his collection [*The Coming of the King*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1075674), Lippincott, Philadelphia, 1897. Here is Bleiler's review of the story:

> Hot romance in the past on the moon. * The moon is gradually losing its atmosphere, and the human population has dwindled to a couple of hundred. The great scientist Darus has constructed a spaceship that will take the survivors to the earth, which is still in the mastodon stage and without a human population. The spaceship can leave only at certain planetary conjunctions. * A complication exists in Princess Callistano. Her people and family were killed in war by Prince Lileo, who has since become her lover. She still loves him, but he is tired of her and plans to abandon her on the moon when the spaceship leaves. * Callistano, however, is not so easily rebuffed. She serves Lileo violently aphrodisiacal wine, and the spaceship leaves while they are making love. On discovering what has happened, Lileo dies of apoplexy, and Callistano does not survive him long. The human race on the moon is dead, but presumably the people on the spaceship were our ancestors. * Written in very purple prose. The story benefits from summary.

**Note:** Bleiler gives the story title as "The Judgment Day in the Moon", but the ISFDB has it as "The Judgment Day of the Moon".

Comment: Holy cow, 1897 -- I would not have guess so early but many inventions, literary and technical, have surprised me with the date they were first created -- did you know there were air rifles in the 17th century?? I was office by a couple hundred years on that one, figuring mid 19th century.

Comment: Humans placed on Earth by an alien? How about the Bible?

Answer (score 12):

There are several works with the more plausible premise that humans were removed from Earth at some point in our evolutionary history, and then returned later. The earliest of which I'm aware is James P Hogan's *Inherit the Stars* (1977).

Otherwise, there's Larry Niven's Known Space series, where humans are descendants of Pak Protectors. *Protector* was published in 1973. Protectors are hominids, but not human (except Jack Brennan), so I think they should count as aliens.

Comment: Niven introduces the Pak as early as "The Adults" in 1967.

Comment: @GorchestopherH When was the idea that humans were descended from the Pak introduced?

Comment: I thought it was Ringworld 1970. I am not sure if Pak Breeders were mentioned in "The Adults". Maybe a Niven expert can verify this.

Comment: Protectors were not mentioned in *Ringworld*.

Comment: "What Can You Say About Chocolate Covered Manhole Covers?" uses the seeding hypothesis and was collected in [*All the Myriad Ways*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_the_Myriad_Ways) in 1971. Can't seem to find the original publication date.

Comment: @MikeScott They do in the Ringworld *Trillogy*. Is it not till the second book (Engineers) that they mention them? Either way "The Adults" is part one of "The Protectors", and predates it by 6 years. I believe, but do not have a quotation, that the Pak were described as ancestors to humanity in "The Adults".

Comment: Come to think of it, ["Bordered in Black"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconstant_Moon#Bordered_in_Black) also uses the seeding hypothesis, though not of Earth. That was published in 1966.

Comment: @all, can someone please provide a more authoritative information on which of Niven's works first introduced not just The Pak but specifically the idea that humans (or all Earth primates) evolved from them?

Comment: @GorchestopherH Correct. *The Ringworld Engineers* has lots of Protectors in it -- but it was published in 1980, well after *Protector*. *Ringworld* did not mention them.

Comment: @MikeScott I suppose it all blurred together in my mind.

Comment: @MarkBeadles In *World of Ptavvs*, humans may or may not have descended from thrintun food yeast, over 1.5 billion years. It's certainly not an example of seeding a planet with human beings, or anything approximating to human beings.

Comment: @dmckee - "Bordered in Black" - a very interesting story - thanks for mentioning! - the fact that it is not Earth doesn't make it a valid answer to this Q.

Comment: @DVK The ISFDB lists "The Adults" as being published in the June 1967 issue of Galaxy. Wikipedia describes it as making up the first half of *Protector*. That would make it the earliest Niven novel to mention the Pak origin of humanity.

Comment: Work, not novel. Duh.

Answer (score 7):

Ark B from The Restaurant at the End of the Universe (1980) probably qualifies.  A ship full of the useless members of another planet are shipped off and crash land on Earth, where they eventually usurp the native population.

Comment: Actually, that idea was already present in the original radio series, which aired in 1978.

Answer (score 5):

L. Ron Hubbard wrote OT III in 1967. It's about [an evil alien overlord accidentally seeding the Earth with humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenu) while trying to kill them:

> The kidnapped populace was loaded into spacecraft for transport to the site of extermination, the planet of Teegeeack (Earth). [...] When they had reached Teegeeack, the paralyzed citizens were unloaded around the bases of volcanoes across the planet. Hydrogen bombs were then lowered into the volcanoes and detonated simultaneously, killing **all but a few aliens**.

Comment: Is that you, Tom?

Comment: @DVK I don't think this the earliest.

Comment: @MarkBeadles - I commented on your answer. "World of Ptavvs" needs an elaboration.

Answer (score 4):

H. Beam Piper's story *Genesis*, in 1951, told of a colony ship to Tareesh from the dying planet Doorsha.  An accident destroys the ship and only a single lifeboat makes it to Tareesh containing 2 men and 6 women.  The lifeboat itself explodes leaving the survivors with a few armfuls of supplies and weapons.

The story follows their struggle to survive, raise children to keep the tribe growing despite their struggle with the brutish manlike creatures there.  At the last it is revealed that Tareesh is Earth, Doorsha Mars.